# How to use JGit api to checkout remote files?

Tags: git, jgit

Using the command line git commands I can do the following

```
git checkout ref/origin/remotebranch projectA/*
```

However if i do the following using jgit, the files under projectA/* are not checked out.

```
    CheckoutCommand checkout= git.checkout();
    checkout.addPath("projectA/*");
    checkout.setName("ref/origin/remotebranch");
    checkout.setAllPaths(false);//tried with both true and false
    checkout.call();
```

How to resolve this in JGit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the glob notation is supported, so try this instead:

```
checkout.addPath("projectA");
```

`setAllPaths` should not be necessary.

Comment: What version of JGit are you using? The following works with JGit master: https://gist.github.com/3338160

Comment: By the way, is `ref/origin/remotebranch` a typo or do you really have such a ref? Normally this is `refs/remotes/origin/remotebranch`.